# Reduce a noisy 14vdc to 12v dc 3A with linear regulator or a switching regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator

I would like to build a very simple constant current and constant voltage power circuit to power a net book at 12V 3A from my car supply that has lots of ac ripple in it from alternator that I cannot seem to fix. It's an old ford focus so I'm just looking to use parts from old power supplies and a few other boards like an lcd monitor board  with functioning starter thingy. Not sure what it does but looks like all possible parts may be just on one bored waiting to be recycled.

So to be clear 
car supply with engine off 12v 
engine on 14vdc fluctuating with rpm to 15v with ac ripple 
want to get 12vdc 3 Amps no matter what rpm the engine is at.

Ps I know I should fix the source of the issue but I cannot find any grounding issues anywhere

---

I made a choke/ inductor but it does not seem to have made any difference. Where should I look for grounding issues ?  I mean I have cleaned the ones I could see in the engine bay but could it be an issue with a ground wire of the lights at the back of the car?  Also  from memory inductors are rated in James's or Henry or something similar. So how do I select a correct inductor value from scrap parts so may not have that specific part. What voltage should I use for the cap to get rid of the whine?  I used same method as mentioned here http://www.instructables.com/id/Car-Radio-Noise-Eliminator/

Comment: Are you saying the voltage peaks at 15V, or the average DC voltage goes up to 15V with ripple (how much?) on it?

Comment: Yeah voltage peaks at 15v with added ac noise from alternator

Comment: How much noise?

Comment: It sounds like, if either will work, you'll be happier with a linear regulator. Switching regulators are more complicated, but they add efficiency when the output voltage is much less than the input. But you won't get much extra efficiency with just a 3V drop. You should be warned that at 3V, 3A, the supply will drop 9W. Also, use lots of capacitors to clean up high frequency noise.

Comment: You can insert a 1mH inductor at the alternator output. The inductor should be rated for double the alternators rating.

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of alternator 'whine' install a 300 uH to 1 mH or so inductor in series with your 12 volt power feed. It should be rated at twice the expected load current.

This is one of those things where large capacitors are not enough. Back when I did car alarms and stereo's, an inductor was the best way to kill any alternator whine.

Grounding problems usually show up as odd radio or AC behavior, changing stations or volume by itself, blinkers coming on, dash lights flickering, etc.

Comment: I made a choke/ inductor but it does not seem to have made any difference. Where should I look for grounding issues ?  I mean I have cleaned the ones I could see in the engine bay but could it be an issue with a ground wire of the lights at the back of the car?  Also  from memory inductors are rated in James's or Henry or something similar. So how do I select a correct inductor value from scrap parts so may not have that specific part. What voltage should I use for the cap to get rid of the whine?  I used same method as mentioned here http://www.instructables.com/id/Car-Radio-Noise-Eliminator/

Comment: If the whine is in the radio then that is where the inductor should be(12 volt power feed). It takes a 1 inch diameter toroid and many turns to get a 1 mH (millihenry) inductor. If you have an external audio amp that needs a filter as well.

Comment: In some cars there is a ground lug welded to the car chassis under the carpet, under the brake pedal. Most items use a ring terminal and a nut to clamp them on.

Answer (score 0):

All filters are voltage-dividers. That means you need **TWO** elements to make a filter.

For this situation, use a large inductor in the power wire, and a large capacitor from the output side of inductor to GND.

Now..... what is Ground?